# Z3PY Hanging on Solver.Check() on formula containing Bool and Int Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, z3, smt, z3py

I'm using Python Z3 to try and satisfy a large number of clauses containing variables and integers. When I run one of my Z3 scripts though, the Python shell hangs. The script is supposed to return SAT or UNSAT, but it does neither. It just hangs. The formula is very long, but I have run scripts with longer formulas and I haven't had any problem with those, so I'm not convinced that I'm encountering some kind of size limit. The only thing that I thought might be causing a problem is how Z3 treats clauses that contain both Int and Bool variables.

My scripts are very long, so I've uploaded them to this [Github Issues Page](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/6921) as text files.

I found a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144365/z3py-sometimes-hangs-on-solver-check-on-formulas-that-it-can-solve) where someone's issue stemmed from using String variables. The fix for this problem was to add a Z3 context to the variables and checker, but that solution hasn't worked for me.

Comment: "Size" of a formula, and how difficult it is to "solve" are not directly related. SAT/SMT is essentially heuristic, and you shouldn't expect size to be the only factor in determining whether the solver will give you an answer. To answer your question, you really need to give us more information. The first thing that comes to my mind is to avoid using `Int`s unless they are really integers. (i.e., unbounded mathematical integers.) Using bit-vectors might be a better choice. But impossible to tell from what you described here.

Comment: The ability to use Ints is what drew us to use the Z3 tool in the first place, as opposed to something like MiniSAT. Using bit-vectors for our logic clauses is very tedious, and we were wanting to move away from it. We're using propositional logic to model transistor-level CMOS circuitry with bidirectional pass transistors, and the Int variables are necessary to avoid cyclical logic loops, which would otherwise cause differing behavior from hardware.

If you follow the Github Issues Page link I provided, the miter.txt file is actually a Python script that hangs whenever we try to run it.

Comment: Cool; sounds like `Int` usage is justified. I assume there's also nothing nonlinear in the equations? (It's too much to ask a stack-overflow reader to read through your script.) My advice would be to try to reduce it to a minimal core that exhibits the problem. Of course, I fully understand that this is much easier said than done. But I doubt anyone can help you on this form (or even at the z3 GitHub page as well), before the problem is reduced to something simple enough to analyze. Otherwise, you're attempting to solve an instance of an NP-complete problem, and it's just too difficult.

Comment: You can at least run z3 with high-verbosity to see what sorts of messages it prints. It's really hard to decipher any meaning out of z3 debug/trace messages, but who knows maybe it'll point to something. (For instance, compare the output of something that finishes quickly to something that fails to terminate.)

Comment: I see, thanks. Can you point me towards documentation that shows me how to use Z3 with high-verbosity?

Comment: `set_param("verbose", 10)`. Put it right after you import `z3`.

Comment: Thank you. I've placed that line in my code and rerun it. As you said, it's hard to tell what's going on. It printed many "smt.stats" lines for a while, then it printed out many "smt.working lines". The last line before I interrupted it read:
`smt.working :conflicts 2730115 :agility 0.13`. Conflicts had been steadily increasing.

Comment: Conflicts mean the solver has to backtrack (roughly). So, the larger the conflicts, you can think of that as the model it is building didn't pan out and has to try something else. You can help the solver by asserting "helper" lemmas if you have any, that is things that should be true of your program that can help it navigate to the "right path." But again, all this depends on the very specific problem you're dealing with.